# Can't display mapped posts from an API using axios inside react component

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-component

I would like to show mapped posts from an API inside the OwlCarousel component (***import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel'***) the code works just fine, ***but only outside*** the OwlCarousel component. You can test on this  CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-rhodes-bv5ot, the code works when you remove the OwlCarousel tag.

```
renderPost = () => {
  return this.state.posts
    ? this.state.posts.map(data => (
        <div key={data.id} className="item">
           <div className="heading">{data.subject}</div>
           <div className="content">{data.message}</div>
        </div>
      ))
    : "Loading...";
};

render() {
  return (
        <div className="container">
          <OwlCarousel className="owl-container owl-theme">
            {this.renderPost()}
          </OwlCarousel>
        </div>
  );
}
```

The code works only when i put the function outside the OwlCarousel component, i think it has something to do with scopes!

```
render() {
  return (
        <div className="container">
          {this.renderPost()}
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think it has to do something with the carousel classNames probably, either check with the inspect element if it the case (height? position?), or provide a code example, such as CodeSandbox or something. It is hard to say anything without that.

Comment: @Faheem https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-rhodes-bv5ot

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
renderPost = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.posts
                    ? this.state.posts.map(data => (
                        <div key={data.id} className="item">
                          <div className="heading">{data.subject}</div>
                          <div className="content">{data.message}</div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                    : "Loading..."}
            </div>
        )
    };
```

And In your render of the Component, you can do same as you have already done,

```
{this.renderPost()}
```

Comment: i've already tried this! the problem persists when i put {this.renderPost()} inside <OwlCarousel>